# How do I share a Typescript module by different projects without duplicating the shared module?

Tags: typescript

I have two folders: `shared` and `project1` in a folder `node`. I am developing several independent Node projects located in the `node` folder.

In `shared`, I have an index.ts and it contains a default export. The `outdir` parameter in tsconfig.json is `./dist`. When built, the directory is like:

```
node/shared/
           src/
              index.ts
           dest/
               index.js
           tsconfig.json
           ...
```

In project1, I have index.ts, and under "normal" circumstances, when built, the directory is like:

```
node/project1/
             src/
                index.ts
             dist/
                 index.js
```

My intention is to use `shared` to contain shared utilities that can be used by different projects in the `node` folder.

When I have a statement `import shared from "../../shared/src/index.js"` in `project1/src/index.ts`, the compiled output in the `dest` folder goes crazy:

```
node/project1/
             src/
                index.js
             dest/
                 shared/
                       src/
                          index.js  <- copied from the shared project
                 project1/
                         src/
                            index.js
```

But it is still not workable, because the node modules installed in the `shared` project are not present in `project1`.

My intention is to have in the run-time environment something simple, with no duplication of common shared code, like:

```
node/
    shared/
          index.js
    project1/
            index.js   <- importing stuff from shared/index
    project2/
            index.js   <- importing stuff from shared/index
```

Is this possible? Or is converting the shared module into an NPM package the only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

```
node/
  project1/
    dist/
      index.js
    src/
      index.ts
    tsconfig.json
  shared/
    dist/
      index.js
      index.d.ts
    src/
      index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

### Shared

This is set up like an ordinary project, except that the [`composite`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#composite) setting must be enabled.

`shared/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Referenced projects must have the composite flag turned on
    "composite": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

`shared/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./dist",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

`shared/src/index.ts`

```
export default 'foo'
```

The output `shared/dist/index.js` isn't too exciting:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports["default"] = 'foo';
```

Because of the `composite` compiler flag, type definitions are also generated:

`shared/dist/index.d.ts`

```
declare const _default: "foo";
export default _default;
```

### Project

`project1/tsconfig.json`

Here, you specify that you are referencing the `shared` module.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {"path": "../shared"}
  ]
}
```

`project1/package.json`

Instead of simply `tsc`, you can use `tsc --build` (`tsc -b` for short). This [build mode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript) automatically rebuilds referenced projects if they are out of date. However, note that there are some specific build-only flags and [you cannot override compiler options with command-line arguments](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25613).

```json
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./dist",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

`project1/src/index.ts`

Use the shared module like you normally would.

```
import foo from '../../shared'

console.log(foo)
```

`project1/dist/index.js`

The source compiles down to this:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var shared_1 = require("../../shared");
console.log(shared_1["default"]);
```

As you can see, it correctly imports the shared module from the `node/shared` directory, instead of copying the files into `dist`.

You do not need to specify the full path of the file (`../../shared/dist/index.js`) because the `main` field of the shared project's `package.json` is set to `./dist`, which resolves to `./dist/index.js`. TypeScript knows that Node.js will resolve the `require` to the appropriate file and therefore knows the types of the `shared` module.

If you do not provide a `main` entry in `package.json`, you'll need to use `import foo from '../../shared/dist'`.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I have some questions. Why does the `import` statement not have to specify the file, ie index.js? How does it infer the module definitions are in index.ts? And isn't the shared module located in `../../shared/dist` as seen from `project1/dist`?

Comment: @OldGeezer I edited my answer to clarify that. It's because the [`main` property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) in `package.json` specifies the entry point of the module, which TypeScript knows and uses it to locate the type definitions.